# CSS module does not styling some elements when i deploy my app

Tags: css, webpack

Im trying to apply css style on specific component in React with css module.
When i run the app localy the styles work correctly, but for some reason when i deploy my app the style does not apply on the outer `div`, only his childs get the correct style.
why is that?

Her is the code:

// React component

```
import { ChatContext } from '../../../../contexts/ChatContext';
import classes from './Humburger.module.css';
import React, { useContext } from 'react';

const Humburger = () => {

    const { show, setShow } = useContext(ChatContext);

    return (
        <div className={classes.Humburger} onClick={() => setShow(!show)}>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Humburger;
```

// CSS file

```
 /*Here is the style which does not apply when i deploy my app*/

    .Humburger {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        flex-flow: column;
        width: 35px;
        height: 100%;
        margin-left: 10px;
    }

/*==========================================================*/

.Humburger > span {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-top: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.Humburger > span:first-child {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `import './Humburger.module.css';` and `className='Humburger'` ?

Comment: @L_W107 what error do you get? Also is your css file really named Humburger.module.css ? and not Humburger.css ?

Comment: I dont get any error and my css file named correctly as you say 'Hamburger.module.css'.
it's so weird

Comment: Can you provide a JSFiddle or something similar with your code?

Comment: What do you mean by "the icon doesn't work" ? and everything looks ok in your fiddle...